# CSS Triangle Shaped Button with Icon using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a CSS triangular shaped button that sits in the top left corner of a `div` using *Bootstrap 4*.

Through the magic of *Photoshop*, here is what I am trying to do.

[image]

But here is the closest I have been able to get with all my trial and error.

[image]

I'm trying to style it in a way that the button gets its colors from one of the `btn-*style*` classes so any color can be used.

***Any help?***

**Here is the triangle CSS**

```
.triangle-up-left {
    float          : left;
    width          : 0;
    height         : 0;
    margin         : 0;
    padding-bottom : 10%;
    padding-left   : 10%;
    overflow       : hidden;
    text-align     : center;
    }

.triangle-up-left:after {
    content           : "";
    display           : block;
    width             : 0;
    height            : 0;
    margin-left       : -500px;
    border-bottom     : 500px solid transparent;
    border-left-width : 500px;
    border-left-style : solid;
    }
```

And the current `div` I am using.

```
<div class="row border rounded p-2 mx-2 mt-3 shadow-sm">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-warning triangle-up-left"><i class="far fa-star"></i></a>

    <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-md-1 p-0 m-0  mx-sm-auto">
        <img src="...image.."" alt="Image" class="img-fluid rounded-circle m-3"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 pl-sm-0 pl-md-5 m-0 ">
     some text
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2  p-0 pt-4 m-0  text-center ">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a snippet without using any Frameworks, hope this might help you.

```js
function myFunction(){
 alert("Hai, It works");
}
```

```css
.box{
  background-color:white;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-left:4px solid gray;
}
button>span{
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:absolute;
  left:12px;
  z-index:1;
  top:15px;
  
}
button{
  cursor:pointer;
  background-image:url();
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:transparent;
  border:none;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-radius:7px;
  
}
button:focus {outline:0;}
button::before,
button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}

button::after {
    border-width: 1.3em;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    border-top-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"><span>☆</span></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used background linear gradient to resolve your issue. Be careful: this trick works only with white background 'cause I set a white triangle mask in `::after` pseudo element to continue to use `btn-*style*` bootstrap classes. If you change `row` background remember to change also the color of `::after` mask!

**EDIT 1:** I put the triangle in absolute position so it does not interfere with bootstrap `col` system (you can remove it, as you want)

```css
.row {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100px;
}

.triangle {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:21px;
}

.triangle::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:linear-gradient(to left top, #ffffff 49%, transparent 50%);
}

i {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row border rounded mx-2 mt-3 shadow-sm">

        <a href="#" class="triangle btn-warning position-absolute">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>

       
    </div>

    <div class="row border rounded mx-2 mt-3 shadow-sm">

        <a href="#" class="triangle btn-info position-absolute">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>

        
    </div>

    <div class="row border rounded mx-2 mt-3 shadow-sm">

        <a href="#" class="triangle btn-danger position-absolute">
            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>

        
    </div>
</div>
```